Fast Refresh on React Native Expo latest version with ios 17.5 simulator
I have created a latest Expo RN application. I have installed brew, nvm, latest node LTS. Same stuff as usual.
After creating a simple Expo app, the fast refresh seems not working on latest version of xcode v15.4 and ios 17.5
I use my personal iphone and the Metro server is working fine. I change anything and it will be reflected.
Been working with RN couple of years but since I switched to an M3 and did my usual install, I cannot develop as before. Any help please?
I have tried to re-install xcode and latest ios package. I have created a simple expo app to test. but nothing fast refresh not working on ios simulator
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "^51.0.11",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.15",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

note from 11/06/2024: I have tested that watchman does pick up all new changes for ts and TSX files. By creating a trigger and looking all logs, watchman does see new changes. So now the issue might be with the ios simulator and xcode ?
